# Cannot use docker-compose with overlay network

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I'm pretty baffled what's going on here, but I've narrowed it down to a very small test case. Here's my docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.7"
networks:
    cl_net_overlay:
        driver: overlay
services:
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
    networks:
            - cl_net_overlay
```

The cl_net_overlay network doesn't exist. When I run this with:

```
docker-compose up
```

It stalls for a little while, then says:

```
WARNING: The Docker Engine you're using is running in swarm mode.

Compose does not use swarm mode to deploy services to multiple nodes in a swarm. All containers will be scheduled on the current node.

To deploy your application across the swarm, use `docker stack deploy`.

Creating network "tmp_cl_net_overlay" with driver "overlay"
Recreating tmp_redis_1 ... error

ERROR: for tmp_redis_1  Cannot start service redis: attaching to network failed, make sure your network options are correct and check manager logs: context deadline exceeded

ERROR: for redis  Cannot start service redis: attaching to network failed, make sure your network options are correct and check manager logs: context deadline exceeded
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

This file was working fine for me on my previous laptop. My docker and docker-compose should be up to date since this is a brand new laptop. Is there some piece of the puzzle I'm missing?

```
05:01:11::mlissner@gabbro::/tmp 
↪ docker --version
Docker version 19.03.1, build 74b1e89
05:01:57::mlissner@gabbro::/tmp 
↪ docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.24.1, build 4667896b
```

Any ideas what's going on here? I've been trying to get it to work all day and I'm feeling a little like I'm losing my mind.

---

Small follow up. The message says:

> make sure your network options are correct and check manager logs

I have no idea how to check the manager logs. That might be a useful first step?

---

Another follow up, per comments. If I try to deploy this I get no logs and it's unable to start up:

```
05:44:32::mlissner@gabbro::~/Programming/courtlistener/docker/courtlistener 
↪ docker stack deploy --compose-file /tmp/docker-compose.yml test2
Creating network test2_cl_net_overlay2
Creating service test2_redis

05:44:50::mlissner@gabbro::~/Programming/courtlistener/docker/courtlistener 
↪ docker service ls
ID                  NAME                 MODE                REPLICAS            IMAGE                                        PORTS
5y7o01o5mifn        test2_redis          replicated          0/1                 redis:alpine   

05:44:57::mlissner@gabbro::~/Programming/courtlistener/docker/courtlistener 
↪ docker service ps 5y
ID                  NAME                IMAGE               NODE                DESIRED STATE       CURRENT STATE             ERROR                              PORTS
0kbph0ie8qth        test2_redis.1       redis:alpine        gabbro              Ready               Rejected 4 seconds ago    "mkdir /var/lib/docker: read-o…"   
inr81c3r4un7         \_ test2_redis.1   redis:alpine        gabbro              Shutdown            Rejected 9 seconds ago    "mkdir /var/lib/docker: read-o…"   
tl1h6dp90ur2         \_ test2_redis.1   redis:alpine        gabbro              Shutdown            Rejected 14 seconds ago   "mkdir /var/lib/docker: read-o…"   
jacv2yvkspix         \_ test2_redis.1   redis:alpine        gabbro              Shutdown            Rejected 19 seconds ago   "mkdir /var/lib/docker: read-o…"   
7cm6e8snf517         \_ test2_redis.1   redis:alpine        gabbro              Shutdown            Rejected 19 seconds ago   "mkdir /var/lib/docker: read-o…"
```

---

Another idea: Running as root. Same issue.

Comment: Check if your node availability is in drain state. Also do you use Linux or Windows?

Comment: This is on Ubuntu 19.04. Checking the node state with: `docker node inspect --format {{.Spec.Availability}} iq` returns `active`. Thank you!

Comment: What happens when you run it as a stack rather than compose?

Comment: Thanks @YamaçKurtuluş. If I try with a deploy it just fails, no logs, no nothing. I updated the original question with details.

Comment: can you run a `docker logs` for any of the service containers? Also does it work when you do not use an overlay network? Also is it possible to recreate the swarm and the network?

Comment: `docker container ls` shows me no containers, so `docker logs` has nothing to work on. If I do `docker service ls` I get the item, but it has no logs. If I switch to a `bridge` network, it works, but I'd like to get `overlay` working. I've tried recreating the swarm and the network. No changes.

Comment: Your missing "piece of puzzle" is docker swarm. Warning is cleary tells about it. Decide do you need multihost deploys or not. If not:  you don't need overlay networks - switch to bridge

Comment: @AlexYu, we do need overlay, though I'm not using it in this case. This exact command works on my old laptop. Something is pretty wrong with `overlay` on this one.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the right plugins (see more bellow on the `docker info` command)?

```
Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
```

It works on:

```
$ docker swarm init
$ docker-compose up
WARNING: The Docker Engine you're using is running in swarm mode.

Compose does not use swarm mode to deploy services to multiple nodes in a swarm. All containers will be scheduled on the current node.

To deploy your application across the swarm, use `docker stack deploy`.

Creating network "stackoverflow-57701373_cl_net_overlay" with driver "overlay"
Pulling redis (redis:alpine)...
alpine: Pulling from library/redis
9d48c3bd43c5: Pull complete
(...)
redis_1  | 1:M 29 Aug 2019 01:27:31.969 * Ready to accept connection
```

When:

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 19.03.1-ce, build 74b1e89e8a
```

and `info`:

```
$ docker info
Client:
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
(...)
 Server Version: 19.03.1-ce
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: false
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: active
  NodeID: ff5mogx0ph4pgmwm2zrbhmjb4
  Is Manager: true
  ClusterID: vloixv7g75jflw5i1k81neul1
  Managers: 1
  Nodes: 1
(...)
```

Comment: One difference I have there is that I lack `ipvlan` in the `Network` plugins. I can't tell if that looks promising or not to be honest.

Comment: Kind of looks like `ipvlan` is a legacy thing.

Comment: Hmm ... Did you try running it with the flag `--force-recreate`? What I can confirm is that I tried with exactly your `docker-compose.yaml` and works on Archlinux with a similar output, that may give you bad hints.